# Template Constructor using STL iterators

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I'm writting a hash table, but I've faced with a difficulty. I want to initialize it with contents of standart containers(vector, list and etc.), like a map:
`map <string,int> m(a.begin(),a.end())`
I have the following definition of class: `template <class key,class val,class hashik=std_hash> class hash_table`.
And I define a constructor:

```
template <template <class> class C> hash_table(typename C<pair <key,val> >::iterator first,typename C<pair <key,val> >::iterator last)
{
    init();
    for(pair <key,val>* it=first;it!=last;++it)
        this->operator[](it->first)=it->second;
}
```

But it doesn't compile. *No matching function for call.* For example:

```
vector <pair <string,int> > a;
...
hash_table <string,int> m(a.begin(),a.end()); //compilation error
```

What am I doing wrong? And what books about templates can you advise me to read?

Comment: Can you please post an [example](http://www.sscce.org/) that someone else can try compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to be too specific about what types you'll accept.  The key thing to remember is that templates will match just about anything as long as it compiles.  If I'm deciphering your code correctly, you have a class like this:

```
template <typename K, typename V> hash_table { /* ... */ };
```

This declares a hash table with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`.  To write a constructor that accepts elements from a map, declare the constructor so it is a template too:

```
template <typename Iter>
hash_table(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    init();
    for (Iter it = first; it != last; ++it)
        this->operator[](it->first)=it->second;
}
```

This will automagically match any iterator that can be dereferenced to get `first` and `second` members.  Among standard containers, that includes `map`, `multimap` and their `unordered_` cousins.  That should be enough to get you started.

Also note that this is a useful trick for when you need a type that you don't know how to spell, such as a complicated function pointer or a lambda (which you can't spell at all).